# Chance to pick highest card out of 3

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Suppose that distinct integer values are written on each of three (3) cards. Suppose that you are to be offered these cards in a random order. When you are offered a card you must immediately either accept it or reject it. If you accept a card, the process ends. If you reject a card, then the next card (if a card remains) is offered. If you reject the first two cards offered, then you must accept the final card.

If you plan to reject the first card offered, and to then accept the second card if and only if its value is greater than the value of the first card, what is the probability that you will accept the highest valued card?

One way to solve this:

$S = \{1,2,3\} , \{1,3,2\} , \{2,1,3\} , \{2,3,1\} , \{3,1,2\} , \{3,2,1\}$

If we simulate through each permutation, the probability that we accept the highest valued card is $3/6 = 1/2$

My question is, is there a smarter way to solve this question more "mathematically" with formulas and logical thinking?

Comment: For a small number of cases, hand counting is a fine approach and you hav done it correctly.  This is known as the [Secretary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem)  The page confirms your strategy and answer.  When there are more to chose from than $3$ the general strategy is to skip the first $\frac ne$ applicants, then choose the next one better than any you have seen so far.  This gets the best applicant in about $\frac 1e$ of the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are only six outcomes, your method won't take much longer than any other method, so there's nothing wrong with it (though if you tried to generalize the problem, it would be an interesting question).

As it is, I'd calculate this by seeing the ways in which you pick the highest card. If you pick it, it's either the second card or the third, as you never pick the first. If the highest card is second, you always pick it, since the first card will always be last, so that gives you a $1/3$ chance of picking it. If the highest card is last, you need the ordering $(2,1,3)$, since $(1,2,3)$ will result in you picking $2$. That gives a $1/6$ chance. Adding the probabilities of the two disjoint cases gives you a $1/2$ chance of picking the highest card.